# How to properly receive a msg via CAN with STM32F105

Tags: embedded, stm32, can-bus

This is my first time programming a microcontroller and I was wondering how to receive a msg via CAN using the interrupt. I initialized my micro, STM32F105, so that only 0x0106 and 0x010A IDs are allowed.
This is the *main* section:

```
int main(void)
{

/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

/* USER CODE END 1 */

/* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

/* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
HAL_Init();

/* Configure the system clock */
SystemClock_Config();

/* Initialize all configured peripherals */
MX_GPIO_Init();
MX_ADC1_Init();
MX_CAN1_Init();
MX_IWDG_Init();
MX_RTC_Init();
MX_SPI1_Init();
MX_TIM1_Init();
MX_TIM2_Init();
MX_UART4_Init();
MX_UART5_Init();

/* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
/* Initialize CAN Filter */
CAN_FilterConfTypeDef sFilterConfig;
sFilterConfig.FilterNumber=0;
sFilterConfig.FilterMode=CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
sFilterConfig.FilterScale=CAN_FILTERSCALE_16BIT;
sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh=0x10A<<5;
sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow=0x106<<5;
sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh=0x7FF<<5;
sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow=0x7FF<<5;
sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment=0;
sFilterConfig.FilterActivation=ENABLE;
sFilterConfig.BankNumber=0;
HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan1,&sFilterConfig);
if (HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan1,&sFilterConfig) != HAL_OK)
{
  Error_Handler();
}

HAL_CAN_Receive_IT(&hcan1,CAN_FIFO0);
HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1,TIM_CHANNEL_2);
HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2,TIM_CHANNEL_3);
/* USER CODE END 2 */

/* Infinite loop */
/* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
while (1)
{
/* USER CODE END WHILE */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    //some code here
}
/* USER CODE END 3 */
```

This is the CAN intialization section:

```
/* CAN1 init function */
static void MX_CAN1_Init(void)
{

 hcan1.Instance = CAN1;
 hcan1.Init.Prescaler = 4;
 hcan1.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
 hcan1.Init.SJW = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
 hcan1.Init.BS1 = CAN_BS1_6TQ;
 hcan1.Init.BS2 = CAN_BS2_1TQ;
 hcan1.Init.TTCM = DISABLE;
 hcan1.Init.ABOM = DISABLE;
 hcan1.Init.AWUM = DISABLE;
 hcan1.Init.NART = DISABLE;
 hcan1.Init.RFLM = DISABLE;
 hcan1.Init.TXFP = DISABLE;
 if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan1) != HAL_OK)
 {
   Error_Handler();
 }

}
```

And this is the interrupt section:

```
void CAN1_RX0_IRQHandler(void)
{
 /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_RX0_IRQn 0 */

 /* USER CODE END CAN1_RX0_IRQn 0 */
 HAL_CAN_IRQHandler(&hcan1);
 /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_RX0_IRQn 1 */

 // other code here
 }
```

Basically, what happens is that when I test my board it seems like the interrupt routine is never executed.. Do you know where's the problem?

Comment: Read the reference manual, get rid of that STlib HAL bloatware, program the registers directly. Enable all recommended compiler warnings, treat warnings as errors. Finally use a debugger to see what your code is doing, check registers, etc. If that's not what you want to do (maybe except the HAL thing), refrain from working on embedded systems (and likely programming at all).

Comment: @Olaf thanks for your advice. I'm already testing with a debugger what's going on. I thought using the code generated by STM32CubeMX would have been a good idea, but it seems like this is not the case, so I'll just read the manual and write directly in the registers.

Comment: Are you able to transmit?

Comment: Olaf is right in his grumpy way about the HAL. It's just terrible and ST Cube is a monstrosity. There are older libraries around that don't use the HAL that aren't as bloaty if you really don't want to go through ground-up software to set-up the registers, but programming them directly really does help you to learn peripherals well and in depth, plus you end up with much leaner code. 

I am not sure you have initialised the interrupts though?

Comment: @Swanand No, I'm not.. All I can see is the idle state so I guess it's something about registers. I'm reading the documentation and checking in the meanwhile HAL_CAN_Receive_IT code to see if all the registers I need are initialized correctly

Comment: @DiBosco I set the RX0_Interrupt in the NVIC settings with STM32CubeMX, my guess is that there's still something left uninitialized but I have to find what's wrong.